# Tesselation in Go-GL

Tags: opengl, go, tesselation

I'm trying to tesselate a simple triangle using the [Golang OpenGL bindings](http://github.com/go-gl/gl)

The library doesn't claim support for the tesselation shaders, but I looked through the source code, and adding the correct bindings didn't seem terribly tricky. So I [branched it](https://github.com/joshwillik/gl/tree/tesselation) and tried [adding](https://github.com/JoshWillik/gl/commit/dc7b1a50a9414908329bb8483656087cc41624b6) the correct constants in [gl_defs.go](https://github.com/JoshWillik/gl/blob/tesselation/gl_defs.go).

The bindings still compile just fine and so does my program, it's when I actually try to *use* the new bindings that things go strange. The program goes from displaying a nicely circling triangle to a black screen whenever I actually try to include the tesselation shaders.

I'm following along with the OpenGL Superbible (6th edition) and using their shaders for this project, so I don't image I'm using broken shaders (they don't spit out an error log, anyway). But in case the shaders themselves could be at fault, they can be found in the `setupProgram()` function [here](https://github.com/JoshWillik/GoWander/blob/tesselation/wander.go).

I'm pretty sure my graphics card supports tesselation because printing the openGL version returns `4.4.0 NVIDIA 331.38`
.

**So my questions:**

Is there any reason adding go bindings for tesselation wouldn't work? The bindings seem quite straightforward. 
Am I adding the new bindings incorrectly?

If it should work, why is it not working for me? 
What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Maybe try incorporating Ferguzz's changes to `shader.Source()` (https://github.com/Ferguzz/gl/compare/go-gl:master...master)

Comment: I'm no Go Expert, but I'm not seeing how changing the Source function to accept multiple strings will help me here. I can give it a try tonight though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Steps that might be worth taking:

1. Your driver and video card may support tessellation shaders, but the GL context that your binding is returning for you might be for an earlier version of OpenGL.  Try `glGetString​(GL_VERSION​)` and see what you get.
2. Are you calling `glGetError` basically everywhere and actually checking its values?  Does this binding provide error return values?  If so, are you checking those?

Comment: My graphics card supports a 4.4 context, but I was getting 0x502 and 0x501 errors, so at least I have something to look into now. Thank you :)

Comment: You're welcome!  If you can get a binding to GLU that'll work with the same GL binding, you should definitely try `gluErrorString`-- I think there are other ways to determine what the error really is, but they'll probably be annoying.